# sampling problem

Tags: statistics

1. Suppose I have a sequence $t_k = m k + q + \epsilon_k$ where $k=1,\dots, N$, $\epsilon_k$ is a random error with mean $0$ and variance which is much smaller than $m$. How do I estimate the values of $m$ and $q$?
2. Suppose now that I only have a subset of the values of $t_k$ let say more than 95% of all samples. How do I proceed in this case?

For the first problem I took as $\bar m$ the mean of the consecutive differences of $t_k$. Then I find $\bar q$ as the mean value of $t_k-\bar mk$. However it seems to me that this is not good, because a small error on $m$ gives large errors on $t_k-\bar mq - \bar q$.

Comment: Did you try maximum likelihood fitting?

Comment: I've no experience in statistics... I added a comment on what I have tried

Comment: You have two options. First one is linear least squares method and second one maximum likelihood. I guess linear least squares is the most straight one for your case.